# How to define XSD to allow any element of integer sequence and with a specific value type

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following requirements and am trying to determine how best to model the XSD to represent these requirements.

My Sample XML would like as below:

```
<Langauge>
    <0>English</0>
    <1>Dutch</1>
    <2>French</2>
    ..
    ..
</Language>
```

The number of elements within Langauge tag would be varying but the element would always be in sequence.

Any advice on how I can define the XSD for the above requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible.

[Valid XML element names cannot begin with a digit](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1179145&seqNum=4).   So by definition, a tag named `<1>` can't be legally defined.

If you renamed the tags to be something like tag0, tag1, tag2, etc. then it would be doable.  You would define Language as a sequence of elements in that order, with all optional.   Note that this would still allow the possibility of using a tag0 followed by a tag4 (without 1, 2, or 3 in the middle) but they'd be in order.

Finally -- even then, you shouldn't do this.  By requiring that these elements be in sequence, you're trying to put an array number into an element name, which you shouldn't try to do.  Instead, just create the same element (something like `LanguageName`) and then use its relative child position as the number that you want.   For example:

```
<Language>
   <LanguageName>English</LanguageName>
   <LanguageName>French</LanguageName>
</Language>
```

In any XML processing framework, it's going to be simple to know that English=0 and French=1 (the child's index under the parent).   So I'd question whether there's a good modeling reason to want to put that ascending number into the element name.